# How to realize interacting business logic of asp.net mvc app with separate listener at one server?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

Suppose we have some **Controller with method FooMethod** and class library project with most important class **ListenerClass**, wich incapsulate huge logic, some working thread, and has **public method GetSomeData**. Aim is interacting Controller instance for different requests with ListenerClass(FooMethods).
*(Actually there are many methods in Listener class with which many methods of many controllers should interact)*

Here I posted illustration http://itmages.ru/image/view/3088345/8a710ec4

The source of the problem is separating reqest handling processes for each separate reqest by asp.net infrastructure. Keeping ListenerClass in Session or TempData is terribly bad practise. So there are two questions:

**1. What form of project** is optimal for containing classes from my class lib? I'm consider windows service, but not sure that it is best choise.

**2.How to organize interacting** between asp.net project and project from 1 question. I'm consider socets using localhost, but it seems to me not rational. And in this case I have to serilize and deserialize data on both ends. I hope MS have developed some technology for interact data between .net processes but WCF.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I chosed use **WCF**. It allows create a srvice and create simple interacting with extern code. It is essential to set **InstanceContextMode** to Single in order to keep some data across different requests. If you shold not use network between service and it's client (as in my case) you may use **netNamedPipeBinding** instead wsHttpBing and another.